# How can I average table rows by timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table in PostgreSQL that is created like this:

```
-- Table: myTable
-- DROP TABLE myTable;
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  "TimeStamp" double precision,
  "Temperature" double precision,
  "Pressure" double precision,
  "Milligrams" double precision,
  table_pkey serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT myTable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (table_pkey)
);
```

Where TimeStamp is some number of elapsed seconds since a particular day.

I see how to average some number of table rows together to produce a condensed table. For example,

```
SELECT AVG("TimeStamp") "Seconds", AVG("Temperature") "Temperature",
       AVG("Pressure") "Pressure", AVG("Milligrams") "Milligrams"
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY null) - 1 rn, * FROM myTable) t 
GROUP BY (rn/120) 
ORDER BY rn/120
```

would output a table condensed by a factor of 120 input rows per output row.

Instead of averaging some number of rows together, I want to average some spans of TimeStamp together. To produce, for example, a table where each row contains the average values over each hour of the day.

**EDIT**

This, combined with changing the timestamp column to type typestamp seems to work:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', "Acquired"), AVG("Temperature"), 
AVG("Pressure"), AVG("Milligrams")
FROM myTable
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', "Acquired")
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: What is the 0 value of your "TimeStamp" column? PostgreSQL has a `timestamp` data type which is seconds elapsed since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. If your timestamp has the same basis, I suggest you change your column to the `timestamp` type so you can use all the date/time manipulation routines that are available standard in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change **"TimeStamp"** column type to *timestamp* type (and maybe change column name to **"Created"** to avoid confusion), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  "Created" timestamp,  -- CHANGED COLUMN DEFINITION
  "Temperature" double precision,
  "Pressure" double precision,
  "Milligrams" double precision,
  ...
)
```

So, to produce, for example, a table where each row contains the average values over each hour of the day, you can use date_part and group by accordingly:

```
SELECT date_part('hour', created), AVG("Temperature")
FROM myTable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY date_part('hour', created)
```

Comment: That gets it part of the way there, I think, but when done with minutes, it looks like it creates a table with sixty rows maximum, and date_part goes from [0...59]. I was hoping to keep years, months, days, etc, and have the time column increment by hours, for example, so two days of acquisition would result in a table with 48 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DATE_TRUNC()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) which will return the full date/time truncated to required precision such as 'hour'

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
    (Created timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO myTable
    (Created)
VALUES
    ('2015-09-25 00:11:12'),
    ('2015-09-25 00:45:46'),
    ('2015-09-25 01:20:19'),
    ('2015-09-25 01:54:53'),
    ('2015-09-25 02:29:26'),
    ('2015-09-25 03:04:00'),
    ('2015-09-25 03:38:34'),
    ('2015-09-25 04:13:07'),
    ('2015-09-25 04:47:41'),
    ('2015-09-25 05:22:14'),
    ('2015-09-25 05:56:48'),
    ('2015-09-25 06:31:22'),
    ('2015-09-25 07:05:55'),
    ('2015-09-25 07:40:29'),
    ('2015-09-25 08:15:02'),
    ('2015-09-25 08:49:36'),
    ('2015-09-25 09:24:10'),
    ('2015-09-25 09:58:43'),
    ('2015-09-25 10:33:17'),
    ('2015-09-25 11:07:50'),
    ('2015-09-25 11:42:24'),
    ('2015-09-25 12:16:58'),
    ('2015-09-25 12:51:31'),
    ('2015-09-25 13:26:05'),
    ('2015-09-25 14:00:38'),
    ('2015-09-25 14:35:12'),
    ('2015-09-25 15:09:46'),
    ('2015-09-25 15:44:19'),
    ('2015-09-25 16:18:53'),
    ('2015-09-25 16:53:26')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', Created), COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', Created)
ORDER BY 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53aaaf/3/0)**:

```
|                  date_trunc | count |
|-----------------------------|-------|
| September, 25 2015 00:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 01:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 02:00:00 |     1 |
| September, 25 2015 03:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 04:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 05:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 06:00:00 |     1 |
| September, 25 2015 07:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 08:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 09:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 10:00:00 |     1 |
| September, 25 2015 11:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 12:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 13:00:00 |     1 |
| September, 25 2015 14:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 15:00:00 |     2 |
| September, 25 2015 16:00:00 |     2 |
```

Comment: I did, but my rep isn't yet high enough for the vote to show.